# sql complex select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, indexing, constraints

I want to enter a fk or index on a column, only if such constraint does not exist. If it exists, and the name is not the one I want, just rename it, otherwise do nothing. For this purpose I am checking the sys tables for SQL server or the all_... tables for Oracle.

Here is my problem simplified as possible:

```
index_name              column_name
on_multiple_columns1    a
on_multiple_columns1    b

on_multiple_columns2    a
on_multiple_columns2    b
on_multiple_columns2    c

on_single_column1       b

on_single_column2       c
```

Now I need a select index_name into @constraintToRename statement, so I can rename the @constraintToRename to 'myName' if it exists and not already having the name 'myName', or just create a new one if it doesn't.
I am coming with the info about the column and the 'myName'
E.g.:

select index_name into @toRename from 'some_index_table' join 'some_other_index_table'
where 'the index is specified only on the column what I am entering right now, so no multiple column indexes are returned and so on'

In my case I want to enter an index with myName = test on column b. When I just select the names for column b I would get 3 indexes (on_multiple_columns1, on_multiple_columns2 and the right one on_single_column1), but I need only the on_single_column1 so I can rename it to test.
How can I do this select?
Something like

```
select ... where column = 'my_column' and count(index_names) = 1
```

or

```
select .... where column = 'my_column' and index_name !corresponds to other columns :)
```

How can I express this in SQL?
Thanks
sss

Comment: use [group by](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) index_name [having](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199) count(*) = 1

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović: the problem with this is that, when I have the where column='my_column', then all indexes are having count(*) = 1. When I don't have the column='my_column', then I get all index_names specified only on one column -> in this case on_single_column1 and 2, but I only want the one corresponding to column b -> the on_single_column1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the comment suggestion above I am now using this one:

```
select index_name from <table> where column_name='b' and index_name in 
(select index_name from <table> group by index_name having COUNT(index_name) = 1)
```

This worked fine for me, thanks